# Error de la compilación No se ha definido la variable - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros, imacros

Estoy creando una macro para que abra 6 url en el navegador, pero me arroja el siguiente error y no encuentro la solución, me marca en amarillo `Sub AbrirUrls()` y después marca en amarillo `CmBlAllTll` este es el nombre de la hoja.

La Celda E3 tiene la siguiente formula `=SI(A3="";"Selecciona la Cantidad";INDICE(Talla_S!$G$3:$G$1000;COINCIDIR(A3;Talla_S!$B$2:$B$1000;"0")))` estas celdas tienen una macro que convierte el texto en url les dejo el código que va en la macro.

```
Public Sub Convert_To_Hyperlinks()
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
If Cell <> "" Then
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cell, Cell.Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

No se si este sea el motivo por el cual devuelve un error.

A continuación de la formula de la macro que abre los links en el navegador

```
Sub AbrirUrls()
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink CmBlAllTll.Range("E3").Value
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim url As String
    For i = 4 To 8
        url = CmBlAllTll.Cells(i, 1).Value
        SendKeys "^t"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        SendKeys url & "~" '"{ENTER}"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
  
    Next i

On Error GoTo ManejadorErrores

If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Valor ingresado no fue encontrado", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Ha ocurrido un error: " & Err.Description
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Depura tu código con F8, mira qué línea exactamente da el error y qué tipo de error. Pero tiene toda la pinta de que no has vinculado bien

Answer (score 0):

Prueba definiendo CmBlAllTll como hoja (Ojo yo la he definido como la hoja1 pero si tiene un nombre es mejor que pongas el nombre). Además, no has creado tampoco la sección para manejar los errores "ManejadorErrores" y te va a fallar. Prueba con el código que te adjunto:

```
Sub AbrirUrls()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim url As String
    Dim CmBlAllTll As Worksheet
    
    Set CmBlAllTll = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink CmBlAllTll.Range("E3").Value
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

    For i = 4 To 8
        url = CmBlAllTll.Cells(i, 1).Value
        SendKeys "^t"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        SendKeys url & "~" '"{ENTER}"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
  
    Next i

On Error GoTo ManejadorErrores

ManejadorErrores:

If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Valor ingresado no fue encontrado", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Ha ocurrido un error: " & Err.Description
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dice, se ha producido el error -2147221014(800401ea)' en tiempo de ejecución:

No se puede abrir el archivo especificado.

Finalizar
Depurar
Ayuda

Muestra esto en amarillo > ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink CmBlAllTll.Range("E3").Value

Comment: Si te da ese error ahora es que lo que sea que hay en E3 es incorrecto y no puede abrirlo.

Comment: Lo que hay en la E3 es lo que comentaba en la pregunta principal, hay una formula aquí está: La Celda E3 tiene la siguiente formula =SI(A3="";"Selecciona la Cantidad";INDICE(Talla_S!$G$3:$G$1000;COINCIDIR(A3;Talla_S!$B$2:$B$1000;"0"))) estas celdas tienen una macro que convierte el texto en url les dejo el código que va en la macro.

Comment: Incluso depurando el código de la celda E3 lo deje así... =INDICE(Talla_S!$C$2:$C$1004;COINCIDIR(A2;Talla_S!$B$2:$B$1004;"2,25 €")*1)

Comment: Adjunta una captura de pantalla con la fórmula y el resultado que obtiene esa fórmula.